# JSON request problems, NSString properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm running into some difficulties making requests to a backend that is being worked on for me. For example, a user I've previously created with the username: "test23" and it's password: "ws0ei" works perfectly when making this JSON request like this:

```
self.username = @"test23";
self.password = @"ws0ei";

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = @{@"action" : @"upload_profile_image",
                                    @"username" : self.username,
                                    @"password_hash" : [self md5HexDigest:self.password]};

NSString *requestString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:kNilOptions error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *escaped = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.host.com/server.php?request=%@",requestString] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escaped]];

- (NSString*)md5HexDigest:(NSString*)input
{
    const char* str = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(str, strlen(str), result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];

    for (int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

However, when testing the same request with the username that I created "test32" and its same password of "ws0ei", the API responds with

```
{
    reason = "Invalid username/password";
    status = "image not uploaded";
}
```

I have no idea what the problem is, I'm thinking it's related to improper encoding or something related to the md5 on the app side and not the backend definitely.

I'd appreciate any help offered. Thank you. **Edit: including some console logs of how user "test23" JSON dictionary, request URL, and request response looks like, and also user "test32" to show you that they're identical"**

Username: test23

JSON Dictionary

```
2014-05-01 20:53:51.311 test[20603:60b] 
{
    action = "upload_profile_image";
    "password_hash" = 19144b5589ca801f459fe42db9ec859a;
    username = test23;
}
```

Request URL (escaped)

```
2014-05-01 20:53:51.312 test[20603:60b] http://www.host.com/server.php?request=%7B%22username%22:%22test23%22,%22action%22:%22upload_profile_image%22,%22password_hash%22:%2219144b5589ca801f459fe42db9ec859a%22%7D
```

Response

```
2014-05-01 20:53:51.850 test[20603:60b] 
{
    status = "image uploaded";
}
```

Username: test32

JSON Dictionary

```
2014-05-01 20:57:00.988 test[20625:60b] 
{
    action = "upload_profile_image";
    "password_hash" = 19144b5589ca801f459fe42db9ec859a;
    username = test32;
}
```

Request URL (escaped)

```
2014-05-01 20:57:00.989 test[20625:60b] http://www.host.com/server.php?request=%7B%22username%22:%22test32%22,%22action%22:%22upload_profile_image%22,%22password_hash%22:%2219144b5589ca801f459fe42db9ec859a%22%7D
```

Response

```
2014-05-01 20:57:01.464 test[20625:60b] 
{
    reason = "Invalid username/password";
    status = "image not uploaded";
}
```

Comment: What is the json string being sent? And are you sure the password hash is correct?

Comment: Please look at my revised post, and yes I'm sure kind sir.

Comment: You're logging the dictionary objects. Can you log `requestString`? And also `escaped`, I think that might be where your problem is.

Comment: Actually, in my revised post I log escaped. Escaped is Request URL in my revised post

Comment: I'm not sure, but is ":" a valid character in a URL? It might depend on the server at the other end what will happen. Perhaps check the documentation?

Comment: It works fine in the URL. No reason why it works in test23 and not test32

Comment: The problem has to be the value of `escaped`. It's impossible for anything else to cause a problem, unless there is something strange going on server side.

Comment: As you can see, `escaped` is identical in test23 and test32, no?

Comment: Why are you so sure this is not a problem with the back end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was indeed a backend issue. Problem has been solved now